# What is the best way to redirect node to node

Tags: 8, redirection

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to create a redirect from one node to another.  For example, say we have two nodes:

```
node/1 | path-one
node/2 | path-two
```

I created the following redirect:

[image]

But when visiting `path-one` it still shows `node/1` instead of redirecting to `node/2`.

The only way I can do it is to remove the path alias for `node/1` and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the redirect when logged out of your admin account as I believe when logged in as an admin any redirects from a page that exists won't get triggered. This is to allow you to be able to still access that page as an administrator

Comment: Cleared cache, cleared browser cache and signed out but it still didn't redirect.